# How to hyperlink at beginning of the bibliography to the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref

I want to add a hyperlink at the beginning of the bibliography to the table of contents:[image]

My (obvious) approach is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{How do I add a hyperlink in thebibliography to the table of contents?}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

% this is the hypertarget I want to put in thebibliography
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

I cite authors and books:  \cite{author1,book1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

%Here I want the hyperlink to the table of contents, 
%but if I don't know how to do it without getting an error:

%\hyperlink{toc}{Hyperlink back to table of contents.}

\bibitem{author1}
This is the info of citation 1.

\bibitem{book1}
This is the info of citation 2.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Using

```
    \bibitem{whatever} \hyperlink{toc}{Hyperlink back to table of contents.}

\bibitem{author1}
This is the info of citation 1.

\bibitem{book1}
This is the info of citation 2.
```

works:

[image]

but I don't know how to remove the number (I tried to search for that approach and could not find anything).

I've seen similar questions in the forum, but they only confuse me more, since I don't see anyone asking for this specific task. However, sorry if this is a duped question, I thought this would be simple but I'm struggling to get the desired hyperlink.

Comment: that is a rather odd place for such a link. Why don't you add the toc to the bookmarks? That's where I would look for such a link. Beside this `\AddToHookNext{cmd/list/before}{Some text before the bib}` before the bibliography should work. Or use natbib or biblatex which both offer options to add a preamble before the bib.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! Your solution works perfectly! I know it's a bit odd, but my idea is to let anyone (in the pdf) to be able to get a look at the bibliography and go back easily to the TOC.

Comment: @CésarVB - Some (many?, most?) pdf browsers provide a button to let users return to the location in the document they were at before they jumped (say, by following a link embedded in a citation call-out) to some place in the bibliography.

Comment: If I want to go *back* in a pdf I use `Alt+left arrow`, if I want to go to the toc (or some other specific location) I use the bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the hyperlinks as part of `\bibname` and `\contentsname`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{How do I add a hyperlink in thebibliography to the table of contents?}

\let\oldcontentsname=\contentsname
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\oldcontentsname}{}{FAILED}

\let\oldbibname=\bibname
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\oldbibname}{}{FAILED}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\def\contentsname{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{\oldcontentsname}\par
  \protect\hyperlink{bib}{\Large Hyperlink to bibliography.}}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

I cite authors and books:  \cite{author1,book1}.

\def\bibname{\protect\hypertarget{bib}{\oldbibname}\par
  \protect\hyperlink{toc}{\Large Hyperlink to table of contents.}}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{author1}
This is the info of citation 1.

\bibitem{book1}
This is the info of citation 2.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but there's a problem: when you add more bibitems (in order to have more pages of the bibliography), the header changes from 'BIBLIOGRAPHY' to 'BIBLIOGRAPHYHYPERLINK BACK TO TABLE OF CONTENTS'. The solution given by @Ulrike FIsher works perfectly, I'm staying with that method.

Comment: I had to use `\patchcmd` to fix the header.  Then again, I could have used  `\patchcmd` to add the link directly.